# How do I make a disabled RichTextbox with a transparent background?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'd like to use the `RichTextBox` to display some rich text but make it disabled, so the text can't be edited.  I want the background to be transparent while it's disabled, but the default behavior is to make the background greyed when the control is disabled.  I've experimented with overriding the `ControlTemplate` and Styles but no luck.

Setting the background to transparent works great as long as I don't set `IsEnabled="False"`.  There is a style trigger in the base `ControlTemplate` that resets the background when the control is disabled, but I can't figure out how to override it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<RichTextBox Background="Transparent" IsReadOnly="True">
```

Works as well as

```
this.richTextBox1.IsReadOnly = "true";
```

You do not need to use the IsEnabled property, as the IsReadOnly does not allow the user to interact, which is what you where looking for right?

Answer (score 2):

you can just set the Background property of the RichTextBox transparent.

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="Resources/nelson.png" />
    <RichTextBox Background="Transparent" IsReadOnly="True">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
                dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
                no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
                eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et 
                ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
                sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
                accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

[image]